# MongoDB : Some packages could not be installed

Tags: software-installation, mongodb

I am trying to  [install mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) in `Ubuntu 22.04`.
Steps which I followed are already given in this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) :

1. `wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -`
2. `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

But Step 4 is giving me error :

```
linux@tux:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```